# hls manually add second .ts file to playlist

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

I've got this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:14
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.416667,
index0.ts
#EXTINF:12.625000,
index1.ts
#EXTINF:8.958333,
index2.ts
#EXTINF:10.416667,
index3.ts
#EXTINF:13.666667,
index4.ts
#EXTINF:3.916667,
index5.ts
#EXTINF-X-ENDLIST
```

m3u8 playlist. If I try to play this in the browser it works perfectly fine. Here's the code of the website I use to play the stream

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>World0</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
        <video width="400" id="video" controls></video>
        <script>
            // const src = "http://localhost:8080/final/index.m3u8" // "https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8"
            const src = "http://192.168.2.166:8080/final/index.m3u8"
            if(Hls.isSupported()) {
                var video = document.getElementById('video');
                var hls = new Hls();
                hls.loadSource(src);
                hls.attachMedia(video);
                hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
                    console.log("attached");
                })
                hls.on(Hls.Events.ERROR, (event, data) => {
                    const errorType = data.type;
                    const errorDetails = data.details;
                    const errorFatal = data.fatal;

                    console.log(errorType, errorDetails, errorFatal);
                })
                hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function()
                {
                    video.play();
                });
            } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
                video.src = src;
                video.addEventListener('canplay',function() {
                    video.play();
                });
            }
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

But now I want to repeat the last section (index5.ts) again. So I did this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:14
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.416667,
index0.ts
#EXTINF:12.625000,
index1.ts
#EXTINF:8.958333,
index2.ts
#EXTINF:10.416667,
index3.ts
#EXTINF:13.666667,
index4.ts
#EXTINF:3.916667,
index5.ts
#EXTINF:3.916667,
index5.ts
#EXTINF-X-ENDLIST
```

As you can see I listed the index5.ts file twice. So theoretically this section should be played double. But when I go to the video-player from the website and skip to the 1:00 mark where normally the index5.ts section should repeat. It just keeps loading and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tag prior to the repeat to indicate that there is a discontinuity between the media file preceeding the tag and the media file that follows.

This is because there will be a timestamp discontinuity between each iteration of the repeated segment, whereas the player expects the timestamps to be incrementing as the playlist proceeds.

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-08#section-4.4.4.3 for more information.

```
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:14
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.416667,
index0.ts
#EXTINF:12.625000,
index1.ts
#EXTINF:8.958333,
index2.ts
#EXTINF:10.416667,
index3.ts
#EXTINF:13.666667,
index4.ts
#EXTINF:3.916667,
index5.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:3.916667,
index5.ts
#EXTINF-X-ENDLIST
```